# Pushing Xamarin forms to Github

Tags: github

I'm trying to push my xamarin forms project to github .
I've tried the regular method following the github instruction & using command line but xamarin forms project usually are big in size so that it won't be pushed throw the CMD and it recommends the Git LFS instead.
however, I found that we can push the project to github
https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-use-git-and-github-in-xamarin-development/
using the GitHub Extension for Visual Studio and I have installed it but the second step is to add the solution to source control.
but I cannot find the latter option in my menu
[image]

so can anyone help me with this problem, all I need to do is to push my project to github if there any other option than the one I have provided in the article above please mention it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If its trying to push a lot, then you are missing a `.gitignore` file. Put this in the root folder of your solution.

[Here is a github list of useful gitignore files](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

A good one to use for this purpose is [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore).

At minimum, have these lines in your `.gitignore` file:

```
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
.vs/
```

`bin` and `obj` are the main folders containing results of building. These are re-creatable from source files, so should not be in repo.

`.vs` is where visual studio keeps all its user-specific files (such as `.suo`).

Comment: can you give me any step by step tutorial about this because i have no idea how it's done.
sorry for this but am really not a github expert i was just using the instruction command line for example android projects and that was it, i didn't need any further configurations.
thanks in advance.

Comment: @AbanoubRefaat - google `using a gitignore file`.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be more a git problem than a Xamarin problem. Xamarin.Forms projects aren't bigger than other projects - but you have to ensure you excluded all the build output from the beginning (using a .gitignore-file for .NET projects) - otherwise you commit binaries and your nuget-feed.

Seeing this menu structure, it seems, you already are working with git (at least with a local repo without remote). So you should check your git repo settings and add github as remote: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have no idea how to do this .
if there is any step by step Tutorial for this .
am using visual studio 2019 and trying to push a xamarin forms project.